# Jquery UI dialog close function "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is my code in js file.

```
<script> 
var originalContent;
$( ".location-edit-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 500
  },
  hide: "puff",
  width:500,
  position: { 
      my: 'center',
      at: 'top',
      of: $('.display')
  } 
  open : function(event, ui) { 
    originalContent = $(".location-edit-form").html();
  },
  close : function(event, ui) {
    $(".location-edit-form").html(originalContent);
  }
});
</script>
```

Everything worked well until I had to use "open and close function".
And it shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

Btw, the order of the scripts I use is below 
jquery-3.2.1.min.js
bootstrap.js
tether.min.js
jquery-ui.js
ckeditor.js
ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js

Comment: there is a typo, add a comma after position object, also I would recommend to you some linters like eslint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot a comma

```
<script> 
var originalContent;
$( ".location-edit-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 500
  },
  hide: "puff",
  width:500,
  position: { 
      my: 'center',
      at: 'top',
      of: $('.display')
  }, // You forgot it here
  open : function(event, ui) { 
    originalContent = $(".location-edit-form").html();
  },
  close : function(event, ui) {
    $(".location-edit-form").html(originalContent);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: @PeterTsai if my answer was correct please consider ticking my answer. Glad I could help.